# How to add a splitted string to a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, split

So i have a txt file with names which i provided at the top of the code. The problem is i want to split those lines into seperate lines if they contain a ' ' (space)

```
John
James Peter
Mary Bob
Thomas
Michael
```

i want it to be like this:

```
John
James
Peter
Mary
Bob
Thomas
Michael
```

.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            #region test2

            StreamReader Fixed = new StreamReader("SSfile.txt");
            List<string> FixedList = new List<string>();
            List<string> FixedList2 = new List<string>();
            FixedList2.ToArray();
            string ReadFixed = Fixed.ReadLine();
            while (ReadFixed != null)
            {
                FixedList.Add(ReadFixed);
                ReadFixed = Fixed.ReadLine();

            }
            Fixed.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < FixedList.Count(); i++)
            {
                FixedList[i].Split(' ');


            }
            Console.WriteLine(FixedList.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();

            #endregion


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

So what should i do??

Comment: Take a look at the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Already did:
            for (int i = 0; i < FixedList.Count(); i++)
            {
                FixedList[i].Split(' ');
                

            }

            Console.WriteLine(FixedList.ToString()); But it prints out something like Sysmte.Collections. bla bla, wait let me edit it in the original post so you can see it clearer

Comment: If you print `FixedList.ToString()` you are printing the reference to the list. If you print `FixedList[i]` you are printing a string within the list.

Comment: Simply calling `FixedList[i].Split(' ')` doesn't do anything - the `Split` method *returns* a string array. It doesn't modify the original string.

Comment: @Mage Xy So what should i do if i want to split those names in that way, and save it into a new list? I tried this but this is a waste...: string[] arrays;
            for (int i = 0; i < FixedList.Count(); i++)
            {
                arrays = FixedList[i].Split(' ');
                Console.WriteLine(arrays);
            }

Answer (score 3):

Use the power of LINQ:

[String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) will split a string into an array of substrings based on the given delimiter.

[SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) will "flatten" a collection. That means you give a method that transforms one item into many items (for example one string into an array of string) and SelectMany will form a single enumerable from it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var names = File.ReadLines("SSfile.txt")
                           .SelectMany(line => line.Split(' '));

           foreach(var name in names)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(name);
           }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Solution works, but please explain how it works as OP (or others who come to this answer) may not understand LINQ.

Comment: Oh yes i would be grateful for that!

Comment: @Chase added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Split each line, example:

```
string.Join("\n","James Peter".Split(' '));
```